# Change the colour of a radio button with Javascript not working via for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have a form:

```
<form id='form' name='form' action='#' method='get'>
        <input type="RADIO" name="test" value="1">
 Yes
        <br>
        <input type="RADIO" name="test" value="2">
 No

</form>
```

and this Javascript:

```
var amount= document.form.test.length;
var radioButtons = document.form.test;

for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode("dsiable this button");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    btn.setAttribute.onclick = function () {
        radioButtons[i].disabled = true;
    };    
    document.form.test[i].parentNode.insertBefore(btn, document.form.test[i].nextSibling);
}
```

This creates the button with the text 'disabled this button', but when clicking it, nothing happens, and no error shows in the console. What am I doing wrong?

If I add a `console.log('test')` in the `setAttribute` part, it doesn't show up, so that part of the code never runs - why is this?

I also tried `btn.setAttribute("onClick", "disable(radioButtons[i])")` with the function

`function disable(radioButtons) {
     //radioButtons.disabled = red;
}`

but this produces the `can't change null of undefined` error, which I do not understand.

What am I doing wrong? Changing the html is not an option.

Comment: You're trying to change the `color` of a radio-input? I'm not sure that can changed; what exactly do you *mean* by the `color`?

Comment: @DavidThomas I just changed my real scenario to something simpler - probably should have checked before. Sorry. I've changed it to `disabled`

Comment: So, now you want create a button that, when clicked, should disable a specific radio-input?

Comment: yes @DavidThomas but really, that will be something much more complicated, but if you could help with this basic part, I'll be able to do the harder part myself hopefully. I know I'm being confusing, but please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using -

```
btn.onclick = function () {
    radioButtons[i].style.color = red;
};
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: Now the function is being called but there's something wrong with the logic of the function. The issue is that when you click on the button, value of i is amount+1 ( due to the for loop). so you have to specify which button you want to change the style for. Ex: radioButtons[0].style.color = red;

Comment: But does the loop not start at 0? Can't I use `i` as the number, why manually? Also, see my edit please - I've changed it to `disabled`

Comment: Can you suggest an alternate method to do what I want? I now get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

To style radio inputs statically

This is how you HTML should look like this:

```
<input class="radio1" type="radio" name="any" id="r1" value="yes" onclick="which(this.value)"><label for="r1" >YES</label> 
<input class="radio1" type="radio" name="any"  id="r2"  value="no" onclick="which(this.value)" checked><label for="r2" >NO</label> </h2>
```

This is how your CSS should look like

```
input[type=radio] {
display: none;
}

input[type=radio] + label::before {
content: '';
display: inline-block;
border: 2px solid white;
border-radius: 50%;
margin: 0 0.5em;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label::before {
background-color: #9F5BA4;
}

.radio1 + label::before {
width: 1em;
height: 1em;
}
```

Now you can do your JQuery selection and change Border color and background color

Comment: I can't change the html - is there any other way? Is CSS really required for such a simple thing?

Answer (score 0):

to add an event listener to the button, use

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
   // some code
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: see my edit please. Using this code with `disabled` results in `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefined` showing in console. Why is this?? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following, assigning the click-handlers to the ancestor `<form>` element:

```js
function disableRadiosByButton(){

  // get all the radio inputs with the name of 'test':
  var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name=test]'),
  // create a <button> element:
      button = document.createElement('button'),
  // create the textNode for that <button> element:
      text = document.createTextNode('disable the following input?'),
  // initialise a variable for use, later:
      tempButton;

  // add the textNode to the <button>:
  button.appendChild(text);
  // set the type of the <button> to 'button':
  button.type = 'button';
  // add the 'disable' class to the element (for styling and filtering):
  button.classList.add('disable');

  // get the ancestor <form> element, add a click-handling function:
  document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('click', function (e){
  // 'e' is the automagically-passed in Event-object,
  // e.target is the element upon which the detected event ('click') was first triggered:
    var target = e.target;

    // if the target's lowercased tagName is 'button' and it has a class of 'disable':
    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button' && target.classList.contains('disable')) {
      // prevent any default events from being triggered (form-submission being one
      // possibility):
      e.preventDefault();
      // disabling the clicked-element's nextElementSibling:
      target.nextElementSibling.disabled = true;
    }
  });

  // iterating over the array-like NodeList of radio-inputs:
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(radios, function (radio) {
    // 'radio' is the current Node over which the forEach is iterating;
    // cloning the created-<button> (cheaper than re-creating one):
    tempButton = button.cloneNode(true);
    // inserting the newly-cloned <button> before the relevant radio-input:
    radio.parentNode.insertBefore(tempButton, radio);
  });
}

// calling the function:
disableRadiosByButton();
```

```html
<form id='form' name='form' action='#' method='get'>
  <input type="RADIO" name="test" value="1" />Yes
  <br>
  <input type="RADIO" name="test" value="2" />No

</form>
```

Or, instead, to toggle the radio-inputs:

```js
// source: DOM node, the input to be disabled by the created <button>,
// text: String, the text of the created <button> element.
function addButtonBefore(source, text) {
  var button = document.createElement('button'),
    text = document.createTextNode(text);
  button.appendChild(text);

  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // caching the current disabled-state (Boolean, true/false):
    var state = source.disabled;
    // inverting the current state, true becomes false, and vice-versa:
    source.disabled = !state;
  });

  source.parentNode.insertBefore(button, source);
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name=test]'), function(radio) {
  addButtonBefore(radio, 'toggle the following button');
});
```

```html
<form id='form' name='form' action='#' method='get'>
  <input type="RADIO" name="test" value="1" />Yes
  <br>
  <input type="RADIO" name="test" value="2" />No

</form>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`document.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTextNode).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).
- [`Element.nextElementSibling()`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling.html).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore).
- [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).